# TabControl Tab Showing - Scoll into view

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a WinForm TabControl that has enough tabs that some tabs need to be scrolled into view using the < > buttons.

As an alternate action you can click on the last visible tab and the tabs scroll left to bring that tab and the next tab into view. This works fine however, the opposite action does not happen when you click on the first (leftmost visible) tab. An expected action would for the control to automatically show the clicked tab and the one before it.

What events or methods can I use to see if a TabPage's tab is visible and to scroll a TabPage's tab onto the screen?

Here's some research code:

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If mbFormLoad Then Exit Sub
    Dim t As TabPage = TabControl1.SelectedTab
    Debug.Print(t.Name)
    Debug.Print("CanFocus:" & TabControl1.TabPages(0).CanFocus)
    Debug.Print("CanSelect:" & TabControl1.TabPages(0).CanSelect)
    Debug.Print("IsAccessible:" & TabControl1.TabPages(0).IsAccessible)
    ' works but causes screen noise
    If TabControl1.SelectedTab.TabIndex > 0 Then
        mbFormLoad = True
        TabControl1.SuspendLayout()
        TabControl1.SelectedIndex = TabControl1.SelectedTab.TabIndex - 1
        TabControl1.SelectedIndex = TabControl1.SelectedTab.TabIndex + 1
        TabControl1.ResumeLayout()
        mbFormLoad = False
    End If
End Sub
```

All of the printed properties return false.

To test add a tabcontrol with several tabs, display form and make it skinny enough that the < > buttons show on the top right and a scroll moves the first tab out of view.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you set selectedIndex to -1 your reference to tabcontrol1.selected tabindex also changed.

```
    'TabControl1.SelectedTab.TabIndex = 1
    TabControl1.SelectedIndex = TabControl1.SelectedTab.TabIndex - 1
    '1 - 1 = 0
    TabControl1.SelectedIndex = TabControl1.SelectedTab.TabIndex + 1
    '0 + 1 = 1


Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If mbFormLoad Then Exit Sub        
    Dim t As TabPage = TabControl1.SelectedTab
    Debug.Print(t.Name)
    Debug.Print("CanFocus:" & TabControl1.TabPages(0).CanFocus)
    Debug.Print("CanSelect:" & TabControl1.TabPages(0).CanSelect)
    Debug.Print("IsAccessible:" & TabControl1.TabPages(0).IsAccessible)
    ' works but causes screen noise
    If TabControl1.SelectedTab.TabIndex > 0 Then
        mbFormLoad = True
        TabControl1.SuspendLayout()

        'store the original selected tab index so you can work with an integer
        Dim index As Integer = TabControl1.SelectedTab.TabIndex

        TabControl1.SelectedIndex = index - 1
        TabControl1.SelectedIndex = index + 1
        TabControl1.SelectedIndex = index
        TabControl1.ResumeLayout()
        mbFormLoad = False
    End If
```